# Why do all my files have a red check next to them when I "check out latest" for the first time from TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm going into TFS and creating a mapping to a local folder, then I right click on the folder I want to check out and click on "Get Latest Version". After I have pulled down all the files I open up the solution in VS and in the Solution Explorer window I see all the files (including the solution and project files) have red check boxes next to them. So now it looks like they all need to be checked in because I have made edits! This is not true, I'm checking these fiels out for the first time and haven't made any changes yet.

How do I check out the folder without it looking like there are already edits that need to be checked in? (no red check next to each file)

Comment: Are the files writable or read-only?  Do you have anything listed in pending changes?  Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem (red checks next to everything in the Solution Explorer window). I resolved it by selecting the solution in the Solution Explorer, and then selecting from the menu bar: *File > Source Control > Refresh Status*. This removed all my red checks.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. It was frustrating because it makes us devs think changes have occurred.  In Visual Studio 2013 it's File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Refresh Status.

Comment: This worked for Visual Studio 2013 too.  The real question is why does it get into this state in the first place???

Answer (score 1):

In Team Explorer (in Visual Studio): Tools | Options | Source Control | Visual Studio Team Foundation Server and select Show Deleted Items...

Then in source control explorer you'll see the items greyed out. You can right click on them and Undelete. (This option will only be available if they, after the undelete, will be included in your current workspace).

Answer (score 1):

The red check marks indicate that there has been a change to the file.  Many of these answers for previous versions of Visual Studio seem correct.  I use Visual Studio 2017 and using GitHub.

If you have several files with the red check mark:
Right click project
Go to Source Control,
Select Commit,
{Follow standard commit procedure}
Enter your commit message,
Sync,
Push.

If there is just one file or you want to commit the files individually:
Right click each file
Select Commit,
{Follow standard commit procedure}
Enter your commit message,
Sync,
Push.

[Right click project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nI08.png)

[Right click file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVEEo.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio 2019, I have unloaded the project and I have reloaded the project. Then it went.

Answer (score 0):

[Identify Version Control Item Status in Solution Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181372(v=vs.90))

> Checked out
>
> Represents an item for which the current user has a pending change in their current workspace, and the item is not exclusively locked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the red X's were appearing because I had moved the files from a Feature branch to an Archived branch (After a successful merge into the main branch).

I tried File > Source Control > Refresh Status however this didn't help.
I didn't want to go messing with cache files.

I found this answer:
Go to Tools/Options/Source Control/Visaul Studio Team Foundation Server. Check if there is a check mark next to "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

I had to right click the particular folder and selected the "Source control" ->"undo pending changes" option.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent 4 hours trying to rectify this and none of the solutions above worked for me, not even unmapping and re-mapping the solution.

In case anyone still has this problem, try removing your workspace and re-adding it.

Below are the instructions for removing and re-adding a workspace in Visual Studio 2019, but it should be similar for any other version as well:

- Go to Team Explorer, scroll down and under Solutions you will see
  Workspace: "Name of your workspace"
- Click on the arrow next to it and select `Manage Workspaces`
- A dialog box containing your workspace will open. Click `Edit` to see
  the paths for Source Control Folder and Local Folder. Make a note of
  them as it will be useful for re-adding the workspace. Close the Edit
  Workspace window, select the Workspace and press `Remove`
- Once it is removed, select `Add` then enter the paths that you noted
  earlier. Press `OK` to confirm and it should re-add your workspace
  without the check marks.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution tested. It turned out very easy. Pending Add + sign or Pending Edit red check sign statuses on projects (below screenshot) of solution are git's statuses, this is very normal, and they will be disappeared after you "git add ." and "git commit -m 'messages'". Done!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After banging my head against a brick wall for 4 hours, it turned out I didn't want to *delete* the folders and files in the Source Control Explorer with the red X alongside them I had previously deleted, but merely toggle the *Show/Hide Deleted Items* button so it made them all disappear:

Highlight the adulterating red-crossed folder/file, and click the 2nd icon from the left in Source Controller menu that looks like an 'Xx'. For me, that's all I wanted to do. My offending files had actually been physically deleted from everywhere except from the documentary evidence that they had once been in the Source Controller. That sorted it for me.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to post this here? It has nothing to do with the problem.